# java swing error dialog box

Tags: java, swing

I have a dialog box to be shown but it is giving compilation errors. The compilation errors are given in the last part.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class SwingDemo {
    SwingDemo() {
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("A Simple Swing Application");
        jfrm.setSize(275, 100);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel jlab = new JLabel(" Swing means powerful GUIs.");
        jfrm.add(jlab);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        public void run() {
            new SwingDemo();
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
    - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
    - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatements
```

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace your main function with this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create the frame on the event dispatching thread.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SwingDemo();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @penta you might find this source useful in understanding the [event-dispatching thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you use an IDE?

Your run() method is inside your main() method. You don't need a run method anyway. Just instantiate from main() new SwingDemo(); and remove the run() function like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         new SwingDemo();
 }
```

Comment: *"You don't need a run method anyway."*  It is best to have one, scheduled on the EDT, when constructing Swing GUIs.  See [Concurrency in Swing: Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for details.

Comment: I agree that you better use a run() method, but not for a simple program like this one.

Comment: *"..but not for a simple program like this one."*  Simple programs like this one should not be subject to inconsistent behavior.  They **will** show that if not started on the EDT.  **Every Swing program, from the simplest to the most complex, should be made on the EDT.**

Comment: Well alright then. My bad! There you go, you have my upvote on your comment.